# how to find the string and it value using grep or awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to shell scripting and started baby steps in it.

I've written shell script recently to call rest API and I was able to execute it without any issues.

I've stored the output in a variable like below

```
{
  "id": 3184136,
  "name": "XXX TEST API",
  "url": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/test/Runs/3184136",
  "isAutomated": true,
  "owner": {
    "displayName": "XXXX",
    "url": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/Identities/dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221",
    "_links": {
      "avatar": {
        "href": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221"
      }
    },
    "id": "dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221",
    "uniqueName": "xxxxxxxxxxx\\ServiceLaunchpadDev",
    "imageUrl": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221"
  },
  "project": {
    "id": "6d5e21e7-c75e-464a-9708-90fbff086902",
    "name": "eDellPrograms"
  },
  "startedDate": "2018-10-11T06:36:50.627Z",
  "completedDate": "2018-10-11T07:04:45.153Z",
  "state": "Completed",
  "plan": {
    "id": "5299555",
    "name": "Smoke Dashboard Peso - DIT",
    "url": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/test/Plans/5299555"
  },
  "postProcessState": "Complete",
  "totalTests": 5,
  "incompleteTests": 0,
  "notApplicableTests": 0,
  "passedTests": 0,
  "unanalyzedTests": 5,
  "createdDate": "2018-10-11T06:36:50.533Z",
  "lastUpdatedDate": "2018-10-11T07:04:45.153Z",
  "lastUpdatedBy": {
    "displayName": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "url": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/Identities/8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3",
    "_links": {
      "avatar": {
        "href": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3"
      }
    },
    "id": "8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3",
    "uniqueName": "xxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "imageUrl": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3"
  },
  "controller": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "revision": 5,
  "comment": "Build Definition : xxxxxxxxxxx \nBuild Version : xxxxxxxxxxx_20180925.1\nConfiguration : DIT\nBatch type : Suite\nTest type : Parallel\nTest Controller Name : xxxxxxxxxxx\nPreferred Agents : ADPTAW10A618|ADPTAW10A619|ADPTAW10A621 \nRequested by : xxxxxxxxxxx\nEmail Request : Y\nEmail To : xxxxxxxxxxx\nEmailCc : xxxxxxxxxxx\nEnvironment : DIT\nTest Setting : DIT\nContinue On Failure : false\nDNS Setting : false",
  "dropLocation": "\\\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\DropFolder\\xxxxxxxxxxx_20180925.1",
  "runStatistics": [
    {
      "state": "Completed",
      "outcome": "Failed",
      "count": 5
    }
  ],
  "webAccessUrl": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=3184136&_a=runCharts"
}
```

from the above output, I'm trying to find the "state" and its value. But I couldn't make that happen. kindly anyone helps me.

`echo $result | grep -o 'state*'`

with above command, I was able to print state. but I'm expecting both state and its value.

Appreciate your help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `echo $result | jq '.state'`

Comment: @kvantour You should quote `"$result"` and moreover probably don't store this string in a variable in the first place.

Comment: `echo "$result" | jq '.state'`

Comment: @ Kvantour ,i'm not sure how come this question is duplicate with mentioned above link? it was totally different form the above. kindly change the status of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for 'state', 'statee', 'stateee', 'stateeee', etc.

The wildcard applies to the preceeding character.

Try this:

```
echo $result | grep -o '"state":[^,]*'
```

It looks for everything up to, but excluding, the next comma.

Comment: Jack if you dont mind , can you please help me to fetch first matched string  value alone(state ) as i've state in multiple places in the file.

Comment: Sure.  Just add ` | head -1` at the end of the above command.

Answer (score 1):

I tried storing your json in a file called n2.json.

```
cat n2.json
{  
   "id":3184136,
   "name":"XXX TEST API",
   "url":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/test/Runs/3184136",
   "isAutomated":true,
   "owner":{  
      "displayName":"XXXX",
      "url":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/Identities/dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221",
      "_links":{  
         "avatar":{  
            "href":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221"
         }
      },
      "id":"dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221",
      "uniqueName":"xxxxxxxxxxx\\ServiceLaunchpadDev",
      "imageUrl":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=dbf722a9-73b0-46d6-a2bd-9835c1f0c221"
   },
   "project":{  
      "id":"6d5e21e7-c75e-464a-9708-90fbff086902",
      "name":"eDellPrograms"
   },
   "startedDate":"2018-10-11T06:36:50.627Z",
   "completedDate":"2018-10-11T07:04:45.153Z",
   "state":"Completed",
   "plan":{  
      "id":"5299555",
      "name":"Smoke Dashboard Peso - DIT",
      "url":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/test/Plans/5299555"
   },
   "postProcessState":"Complete",
   "totalTests":5,
   "incompleteTests":0,
   "notApplicableTests":0,
   "passedTests":0,
   "unanalyzedTests":5,
   "createdDate":"2018-10-11T06:36:50.533Z",
   "lastUpdatedDate":"2018-10-11T07:04:45.153Z",
   "lastUpdatedBy":{  
      "displayName":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "url":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/Identities/8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3",
      "_links":{  
         "avatar":{  
            "href":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3"
         }
      },
      "id":"8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3",
      "uniqueName":"xxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "imageUrl":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8de2a654-063b-48bd-8101-87e4ec2f05e3"
   },
   "controller":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
   "revision":5,
   "comment":"Build Definition : xxxxxxxxxxx \nBuild Version : xxxxxxxxxxx_20180925.1\nConfiguration : DIT\nBatch type : Suite\nTest type : Parallel\nTest Controller Name : xxxxxxxxxxx\nPreferred Agents : ADPTAW10A618|ADPTAW10A619|ADPTAW10A621 \nRequested by : xxxxxxxxxxx\nEmail Request : Y\nEmail To : xxxxxxxxxxx\nEmailCc : xxxxxxxxxxx\nEnvironment : DIT\nTest Setting : DIT\nContinue On Failure : false\nDNS Setting : false",
   "dropLocation":"\\\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\DropFolder\\xxxxxxxxxxx_20180925.1",
   "runStatistics":[  
      {  
         "state":"Completed",
         "outcome":"Failed",
         "count":5
      }
   ],
   "webAccessUrl":"http://xxxxxxxxxxx/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=3184136&_a=runCharts"
}
```

Then use `jq` on top of this:

```
jq -r '.state' n2.json 
Completed
```

Comment: Yes, `jq` is a cleaner way to deal with JSON objects in bash.

Comment: @SivaSankaraRaoBacha I used file, because it is quite cleaner to paste it here than pasting a variable. Otherwise the answer was simple, `echo $var | jq -r '.state' ` 
That was just for your understanding.